$n$-th root function in an ordered field.
In recent days, I have been studying ordered fields, and I was able to prove that any ordered field is a topological field. Now, I came up with the following question:
Suppose $k$ is an ordered field that satisfies the following two properties:
(1) for every $x \in k$ with $x > 0$ and for every positive integer $n$, there exists $y \in k$ such that $y^n = x$
(2) if $k_{+}$ denote the set of all postive elements of $k$, then for every positive integer $n$, the function $f_{n}: k_{+} \rightarrow k$, defined by $f_{n}(x) = y$ where $y^n = x$, is continuous.
then does this imply that $k$ is a real closed field? If not, then what is an example of such an ordered field $k$ that is not a real closed field and satisfies the above two property?
I know that any real closed field $k$ satisfies the above two properties. Also, if we consider the field of rationals $\mathbb{Q}$ and generate the field $k$ by adjoining all the $n$-th roots of the positive rationals with $\mathbb{Q}$, then certainly $k$ is an example of an ordered field satisfying the above two properties, but I really don't know whether $k$ is also a real closed.
Please help me, I am really stuck!

I think your last $k$ is a counterexample - it doesn't contain any root of any degree-5 rational polynomial with Galois group $S_5$.
